# Program to creating WordPress user login system for some defined user roles

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I have updated my code, but the problem is get_the_ID not getting any value. Can you please help. This code was adding function.php in child theme.

```
// Works in single post outside of the Loop
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'myplugin_auth_signon', 30, 3 );
function myplugin_auth_signon( $user, $username, $password ) {
        $user       =   get_user_by( 'login', $username );
        $roles      =   $user->roles['0'];

            $id = get_the_ID();
            echo $id;
            if ( is_page( $id == 400380 ) )
            {
                echo "Employee Page";
                $user = new WP_Error( 'denied', "Customer have no permission to login from this employee login form" );


            }
            if ( is_page( $id == 399649 ) )
            {
                echo "Customer";

            $user = new WP_Error( 'denied', "Employee have no permission to login from this customer login form" );


            }



    return $user;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict other role from login use `authenticate` filter hook.

```
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'myplugin_auth_signon', 30, 3 );

function myplugin_auth_signon( $user, $username, $password ) {
        $user       =   get_user_by( 'login', $username );
        $roles      =   $user->roles['0'];

        if($roles != 'sales' && is_page('YOUR_SALES_PAGE_ID')){
            $user = new WP_Error( 'denied', "You have not permission to login from this form" );
            return $user;
         }
    return $user;
}
```

Replace `YOUR_SALES_PAGE_ID` with your current sales login page id.

For more help see this link : [Click here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/authenticate)

Comment: This is working. But If I created two pages of employee login and customer login. Employee login page stopped all logins of customer user and Customer login page stopped employee users. How to do this?

Comment: use sales page id in if block , i have modified the code please see the above code.

Comment: In this page is_page('PAGE_ID') is not working. Means its showing empty value.

Comment: try using global $post , and compare $post->ID with your page ids. see what $post is coming within function using print_r($post);

Answer (score 0):

User roles comes from `database` ? check it before, then do your logic.

Comment: Yes, Its comes from database. If I print $username in foreach loop then it shows all basic and sales role users.

Comment: you have sellers and buyers, sellers after logging need to go their personal page and buyers go to homepage ? like this ?

Comment: if that is what you want, you can just use switch(userGroup) instead of foreach

Comment: No, actually I need two login pages. One from Employee and One from other customers. Customer including multiple roles. I need restriction from both pages. Example. If anyone open employee login page, its only login for employees not any customers